# query in postgres by timestamp minutes

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4

I'm wondering how to do a group by query where I need to group all the data of the same minute in my db to sum all of them.

```
ws_controller_hist=>  SELECT timestamp, type, medium from default_dataset where type like 'status_devices' and timestamp> current_timestamp - interval '60 minutes' and organization_id = '9fc02db4-c3df-4890-93ac-8dd575ca5638' order by timestamp asc;

       timestamp        |      type      | medium
------------------------+----------------+--------
 2017-12-17 12:44:00+00 | status_devices | {1,0}
 2017-12-17 12:44:00+00 | status_devices | {1,0}
 2017-12-17 12:44:00+00 | status_devices | {1,0}
 2017-12-17 12:44:01+00 | status_devices | {1,0}
 2017-12-17 12:44:01+00 | status_devices | {1,0}
 2017-12-17 12:44:10+00 | status_devices | {0,1}
 2017-12-17 12:44:10+00 | status_devices | {0,1}
```

Doing this query

```
ws_controller_hist=>  SELECT timestamp, type, sum(medium[1]) from default_dataset where type like 'status_devices' and timestamp> current_timestamp - interval '60 minutes' and organization_id = '9fc02db4-c3df-4890-93ac-8dd575ca5638' group by timestamp, type order by timestamp asc;

       timestamp        |      type      | sum
------------------------+----------------+-----
 2017-12-17 12:44:00+00 | status_devices |   3
 2017-12-17 12:44:01+00 | status_devices |   2
 2017-12-17 12:44:10+00 | status_devices |   0
```

I want to get 5 in sum, which is the total in the minute 44 understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `date_trunc()`:

```
select date_trunc('minute', timestamp) as timestamp_min, type, 
       sum(medium[1])
from default_dataset
where type like 'status_devices' and
      timestamp > current_timestamp - interval '60 minutes' and
      organization_id = '9fc02db4-c3df-4890-93ac-8dd575ca5638'
group by timestamp_min, type
order by timestamp_min asc;
```